# Override dialog onBackPressed()?

Tags: android, dialog

How would I override a `Dialog`'s `onBackPressed` to close the dialog as well as calling `finish()` on the `Activity` it is located in?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can use [`setOnCancelListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnCancelListener.html):

```
dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)
    {
         MyActivity.this.finish();
    }
});
```

You need to finish only your activity. Dialog will be dismissed automatically.

Comment: +1 for pointing me in the right direction, the effect I was looking for is the onDismissListener but close enough :-)

Comment: onDismissListener overwrite the positive and negative buttons too. So if you are looking to overwrite backpressed and clicking anywhere outside dialog, onCancelListener is better.

Comment: Same to me. I am using a class that extends dialogfragment so I only override the method onCancel() in my class.

Answer (score 30):

```
dialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                               dialog.cancel();
                               return true;
                            }
                         return false;
                    }
                })
```

Answer (score 5):

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  return new Dialog(getActivity(), getTheme()){
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
      // dismiss();
      // activityReference.finish();
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case i use DialogFragment, which is still a dialog..
so i overriden `onCancel()` in my dialog, and it reacts like `onBackPressed()` of the Activity everytime i click the back button when dialog is shown.

```
@Override
public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) 
{
    super.onCancel(dialog);
    Log.i("RecDialog.onCancel()", "onCancel");
}
```

hope i helped.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin version:

```
dialog?.setOnKeyListener { dialog, keyCode, event ->
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                //dialog?.cancel() //or your implementation            
            }
            false
        }
```