# Override Dialog's OnBackPressed

Tags: android

How can I specifically override just the back button while within a dialog to finish the entire activity and not just the dialog.

Using setOnCancelListener and setOnDismissListener do not work because there are other times that I simply close the dialog without closing the whole activity behind it.

Edit

Thanks Shubayu that may work!

I was also able to access just the back button in a dialog through this function.

```
dialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        finish();
        }
    return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: You can also refer to this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6205043/1603849

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override

> public void onBackPressed ()

of the activity and put in the way you want the behavior in it. Also set a boolean from your dialog which you use inside onBackPressed() of the Activity. if the boolean is true, run the disabling part of the onBackPressed() code else don't.

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Override  
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {    
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){        
        // your logic goes here   
            return true;    
        }    
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

use the above code::

Answer (score 0):

You can use : `dialog.setOnCancelListener(.....)`
first set `dialog.setCancelable(true);`

than you can place below code :

```
  dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)
    {
         // add code backpress 
    }
});
```