# Android Alert dialog is dismissing on Back press?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

when i click on system back button my alert dialog dismiss, i don't want to dismiss my alert, my code is here:-

```
fun shoWResultPopUp() {
    if (!isFinishing()) {
        val mBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@ExamActivity)
        val mView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.show_result_popup, null)
        val mResult = mView.findViewById(R.id.resultBtn) as Button
        mBuilder.setView(mView)
        val dialog = mBuilder.create()
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.show()

        mResult.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, ResultActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    return
}
```

Comment: If your activity destroyed dialog will dismiss

Comment: set dialog.setCancelable(false) below   val dialog = mBuilder.create()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set :

```
dialog.setCancelable(false)
```

As per the Android documentation for this method:

> Sets whether this dialog is cancelable with the
>         {@link KeyEvent#KEYCODE_BACK BACK} key.

So this is exactly for the case you want.

Note:

dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside is for preventing/allowing popup to dismiss when touched outside the popup, not back button. Docs:

> Sets whether this dialog is canceled when touched outside the window's
>         bounds. If setting to true, the dialog is set to be cancelable if not
>         already set.

Comment: you need setCancelable(false)

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link
[Dismiss Dialog onBackPressAndroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204972/override-dialog-onbackpressed)

```
dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)
    {
         MyActivity.this.finish();
    }
});
```